# Compilar e executar projeto via linha de comando

Tags: java, android, android-studio, eclipse, compilação

Tenho uma aplicação Android desenvolvida no Eclipse. Eu sei que é possível compilar e executar um projeto a partir do *console*, porém não sei como fazer isso.

Os passos básicos para compilar um programa `JAVA` é salvar com o mesmo nome da classe seguido de `.java` e executar o seguinte comando:

```
#javac HelloWordConsole.java
```

Porém pretendo executar este processo para criação do `.apk` e instalar direto no dispositivo via USB. Como posso fazer isso usando o CMD do Windows tanto para Eclipse IDE quanto para Android Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As aplicações Android utilizam o Gradle para automatização de compilação. Portanto para compilar o código basta rodar o comando na pasta onde tem o arquivo `build.gradle`.

Para compilar um APK de depuração, abra o CMD e navegue para a raiz do diretório do projeto — no Android Studio, selecione `View > Tool Windows > Terminal`. Para iniciar uma compilação de depuração, chame a tarefa `assembleDebug`:

```
gradle.bat assembleDebug
```

O comando no MacOS e Linix é:

```
$ chmod +x gradle
$ ./gradle assembleDebug
```

PS: É necessário ter o gradle instalado.

Referencia: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

Android usa o sistema de construção Ant. Para que você possa criar um **build.xml** e arquivo `build.properties` para o seu projeto.

Você vai precisar para criar o **build.xml** arquivo primeiro no entanto:

```
android update project -p.
```

Isso irá gerar um arquivo **build.xml**.

Provavelmente, você deve personalizar as etapas de construção e metas para o seu projeto. Uma boa idéia, no seu caso seria a de ter o **build.properties** arquivo gerado pelo sua IDE para a compilação específica. Então incluí-lo através do arquivo **build.xml**.

Em particular, será necessário especificar no arquivo **build.properties**, onde as chaves de assinatura são, e que a senha é:

Build.Properties:

```
key.store=keystore.dat
key.alias=signing_key
key.store.password=password123
key.alias.password=password123
```

O processo de construção utilizando ant também permite que você faça as substituições de variáveis ​​em arquivos Java, que pode ser uma outra idéia. Seria permitem que você personalize o processo de construção ainda em um cliente por base cliente.

Por padrão, a compilação é acionado por:

```
ant clean
ant release
```

Comment: "Você vai precisar para criar o build.xml arquivo primeiro no entanto:" ? Você pegou isso em algum lugar? A tradução parece não estar lega.

Comment: Qual diretório deve entrar para que o "android" seja um comando executável para poder criar o build.xml?

Comment: Desculpe minha péssima tradução @seamusd. Eu peguei a resposta nesse link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15285617/6362228

Comment: Não estou usando chave de assinatura. Pretendo compilar somente como debug. Minha intenção é fazer exatamente o que o botão *run* do Eclipse, porém via linha de comando. Eu já tinha visto essa resposta no SO global, porém não consegui compreender muito bem.

Comment: Encontrei essa outra resposta, aonde explica como fazer para compilar no modo debug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433396/6362228